# How to align icon in the center of the button in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch. I have a button with a compose icon. The icon appears in the right bottom corner of my button as per the given size of the button. Can anyone help me in aligning it? iconAlign attribute is not working for me.

```
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            ui: 'action',
                            iconMask: true,
                            iconCls: 'compose',
                            iconAlign:'center',
                            width:35,
                            height: 25,
                            action:'landedInfo'
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the margin in css helped me put the icon in the center:

```
.x-tab .x-button-icon.compose,.x-button .x-button-icon.x-icon-mask.compose
{

margin-left:-5px;
margin-top:-5px;
margin-right:-7px;
margin-bottom:-5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the padding property to 0 because the width and height you provide are too small and therefore are messing with the 'center' value you provide for 'iconAlign':

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    ui: 'action',
    iconMask: true,
    iconCls: 'compose',
    iconAlign:'center',
    width:35,
    height: 25,
    padding:0,
    action:'landedInfo'
}
```

One way to see it is to increase to width and height to, say 100x50, then you will get a centered icon without touching the padding property...
I admit this might be tricky to spot at first.

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't want to increase the button size. Well, i could achieve it using css. Thank you borck

Comment: You don't have to, you just set the 'padding' to 0 and you will have a centered icon without changing the size. The thing with changing the button size was just for explanation purpose. You shouldn't need css...

Answer (score 0):

I tries this and works for me:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    ui: 'normal',
    text:'LOGOUT',
    iconMask: true,
    iconCls: 'user',
    iconAlign:'center',            
     padding:0,
    cls: 'x-iconalign-top',

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use icon-font, you can do it with css.

```
.x-button-icon {
    /*Icon centering*/
    position:absolute;
    width:1em;//set width of icon relative(icon is font)
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-0.5em;//half of icon height shift back
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-0.5em;//half of icon width shift back
}
```

[You can also absolutey position a component in Sencha Touch using the top, right, bottom and left configurations of any component. This works like the position: absolute CSS code.](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/floating_components)